# What is a non-Jew's purpose in life?

Tags: gentiles, hashkafah-philosophy

What does a non-Jew have to do in life? Why did God create non-Jews?
A Jews purpose in life is to learn Torah and do Mitzvos. What should a non-jew be spending his time doing?

Comment: Probably depends on the person.

Comment: i mean in general like jews keep torah. They do noahide but those are prohbitions what should they be doing?

Comment: Why don't you [edit] that into your question to elaborate? The more specific you are, the better your answers will be as they will discuss what you want them to.

Answer (score 2):

In Eruvin 43b, the Bavli says that if moshiach comes on Friday they will prepare the shabbos for us.

Comment: What should they do until then?

Comment: Learn to prepare the Shabbos which requires technical knowledge and proper kavanah?

Comment: Further, I recall (without a source at hand) that Goyim too can bring korbanot to the Beit HaMikdash. They therefore have their own mitzvot (including The Noahide Laws) through which to reveal G-dliness in the Creation thereby earning their portion in the World to Come.

Answer (score 1):

לעבדה ולשמרה. Their purpose is for this world. They are supposed to run it well, behave properly and morally, and develop the natural world. They aren't בני עולם הבא just like other creations aren't. When the world ends everything in it ends. Those who are imbued with a נשמה, have an element of עולם הבא which will live on in עולם הבא. Without that there is nothing to live on in a realm devoid of our current reality.

The Rambam writes that if they do decide to do good things for Hashem's sake then they too live on in עולם הבא.

Comment: "They aren't בני עולם הבא" Isn't that contradicted by your last paragraph?

Comment: Yes; even the strictest sources concede that righteous non-Jews have a share in the World to Come.